# fill cells with formula 'MATCH', where the lookup_value increments but lookup_array stays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, in this case:

```
1| A     |    B   |     C  |
2|MyData | Lookup | Result |
3|Apple  | Grape  |   4    |
4|Banana | Cherry |   3    |
5|Cherry | Cat    |  #N/A  |
6|Grape  | Dog    |  #N/A  |
7|Mango  | ...    | ...    |
8|       | ...    | ...    |
```

I know the formula for cell C3 is `=MATCH(B3,A3:A7,0)`.
Then for C4, it's `=MATCH(B4,A3:A7,0)`.

The issue is, I can't find a way to copy it down. Excel tries to increment the range offset (i.e. change A3:A7 to A5:A9) and I can't find a way to stop this.

Obviously I don't want to fill the formula cell-by-cell, so is it possible to let Excel fill it for me, while incrementing `lookup_value` without incrementing `lookup_array`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this article about [absolute and relative cell references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

A relative cell reference uses just the column letter and the row number. Think about this in relation to the current cell. Think of the current cell as "that's **ME**".

Let's say the current cell is B2 and the formula in that cell is `=A1`.

For Excel, this relative reference means "the cell one column to the left of **ME** and one row above **ME**".

If you copy the formula down, it will still be the same relationship to the current cell, i.e. one column to the left and one row above "**ME**" or the current cell.

With a $ sign you can throw an anchor and hook a cell reference to an absolute position. The "hook" can be used for either the column letter, or the row number, or both.

So, using our above formula in cell B2:

`=$A1` means a cell in column A, but one row above **ME**. If you copy that formula down it will change to `=$A2` and `=$A3` etc, and always refer to column A and always refer to one row above the current row (**ME**). If the formula is copied to the right, the $ sign will lock the column and it will not change. The row will stay the same, anyway, if the formula is copied sideways.

If you use a dollar sign only in front of the row number like this:

`=A$1` it means the cell in row 1 in the column to the left of **ME**. If you copy that formula down, the row number will not change, because it is locked with the $ sign. If you copy the formula to the right, the column letter will adjust to B, then C, then D, etc., because that will be relative to the current cell, the "**ME**".

If you use a $ sign in front of both the column letter AND the row number, the cell reference will not change when copied anywhere.

With this in mind, lock the reference for the range that you want to use for the Match function. You always want to look in A3 to A7, so you need to use `$A$3:$A$7` in the formula

```
=MATCH(B3,$A$3:$A$7,0)
```

Don't worry about the B3, because you'll be copying DOWN, so only the row number of the B3 will change to B4, B5, etc. But you ALWAYS want to look in A3:A7, so you want to make at least the row references of that range absolute. Making the column references absolute is not required in this scenario, but it does not hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `$` `=MATCH(B3,$A$3:$A$7,0)`.